# How to deploy a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, aws-lambda, deployment, serverless

I was trying to deploy a Lambda function by running this command:

```
sls deploy function --function [myFunction] -s production
```

And I got this error:

> Please run "serverless deploy" to deploy your service. After that you can redeploy your services functions with the "serverless deploy function"

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have to create the entire CloudFormation stack first. Run `sls deploy -s production` to create the lambda functions, IAM roles, http/eventbridge events, etc...

Once the lambda function and all associated resources are deployed, you can then simply update the lambda function with the command you posted. In general I do like to use the `sls deploy function` command if I'm only making code changes, because the lambda is a lot quicker to update, but there are situations where you need to deploy the entire service.